# How can I make the selected menu option return to normal when another is clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, menu, icons

I have a menu made up of eight image input icons.
Ive used Javascript to make the clicked icon turn blue.
However, I need it to return to normal when another icon is clicked. 
Is there a pure javascript solution to this?

This is an example of how I turn the buttons blue..

The button is made up of a clickable icon, and a label underneath.
The label underneath is what I change to blue when clicked.

I queried all the buttons to determine which was clicked, and used the id of the clicked button to change the text underneath the icon blue, aswell as the title of the section of the page that the button links to, thats why I matched the id of the icon to the title of the section.

the label below is simply changed by accessing the style property of the span I enclosed it in, as shown below...

```
this.id.search("routenav");
       if(this.id.match("routenav")) {
            document.getElementById("routetitle").style.color = 'blue';

            var b = document.getElementById("b");
            b.style.color = 'blue'
            b.style.fontSize = '30px';

        }
```

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: How do you make the icons turn blue? Some code would definitely help us understand the problem better.

Comment: I've edited the question to show my code and explain a bit more :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know how to return the label back to it's original colour when another icon is clicked, and make the new icon turn blue instead.

Comment: What you need to do is add a CSS _class_, i.e. `.active`, to the selected element.  But the first thing you will need to do with your JavaScript is to remove that class from all navigation elements creating a blank slate.  Then add the class.  So clicking a navigation element would first remove that class from all elements, then add it.  You could do this without a class and just set all elements color to _black_ then change the selected one to _blue_.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplistic jQuery solution assuming you have navigation similar to the HTML below.  This can easily be configured to be used for anchor tags () etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5jxh/

*HTML*

```html
<ul id="nav">
     <li>one</li>
     <li>two</li>
     <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

*CSS*

```css
ul, li {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
     font-size: 25px;
}
li {
     font-size: 25px;
     cursor: pointer;
}
.active {
     color: blue;
}
```

*jQuery*

```js
$('#nav').on('click', 'li', function() {

    /* remove 'active' class from all possible navigation elements */
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

    /* add 'active' class to current element */
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```